# How can I protect groups from each other in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In a single AWS account, I want to be able to give access to two groups of users that will be setting up different applications. Each group should be able to create new EC2 machines, S3 buckets, RDS databases, etc as well as delete them, but they shouldn't be able to delete each other's or affect them in any other way.

Is this possible? How is this best achieved?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

**Accounts**

The highest level of isolation is to give them separate accounts. This keeps them completely separate, with no overlap at all. This is what enterprises typically do - dozens or even hundreds of accounts ins't unusual.

You can create an AWS organisation so you get one bill. This also allows you to use Service Control Policies, which lets you control what services can be used, what API calls are allowed and not allowed, and you can do role based permissions if you want to. I suggest not using role based permissions in SCP as it's complex.

You have to have significant automation to make this practical with large numbers of accounts, and the cost of the architects and devops engineers is high, but for a few accounts it's easy enough to do manually.

The AWS Landing Zone / Control Tower helps set this up. It's also complex.

**VPCs**

The next level of isolation down is to give each application a VPC. Set up your IAM users into ground, and make sure your IAM policy only lets users act on their own VPC. This is good isolation, but AWS rate / resource limits are account based so one very busy or DDOS'd application can affect the other. You have to be careful with your IAM policies.

**Subnets**

The next level of isolation down is subnets. Less isolation, slightly more difficult to administer.

**And On**

Next level down is probably resource level permissions, but that's not really practical.

**User Management**

You can set up identity federation from an existing active directory server if you have one. With this you can let users assume IAM roles based on their AD group, which is really helpful. You can then use role based permissions, so you can define say users, administrators, security operations, or any groups you like really. If you don't use roles like this groups can be similar.

You can have a central "users" account, letting users assume roles into the workload accounts. This is fine but gets messy after you get to maybe a dozen accounts.

I find it best to create and push out IAM policies using CloudFormation, so it's easy to update policies. SCP doesn't support CF yet, but you can write policies and upload then using the API, which automates their distribution.

**Which to Choose**

Given your question I'm guessing you're fairly new to AWS. Having a separate account for each application or team is easier to implement. I suggest you seriously consider that option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [attribute-based access control](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/simplify-granting-access-to-your-aws-resources-by-using-tags-on-aws-iam-users-and-roles/) (ABAC). 
You just group your IAM principals by attaching tags and create tag-based access control policies according to your needs.

This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/working-backward-from-iam-policies-and-principal-tags-to-standardized-names-and-tags-for-your-aws-resources/) demonstrates a sample use-case of tag-based authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to protect groups from each other in AWS by using AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) and Resource-Level Permissions.

Here's an approach you can take:

1. Create two IAM groups, one for each team.
2. Define policies for each group that grant permissions to the AWS services they need, such as EC2, S3, and RDS.
3. Use Resource-Level Permissions to limit each group's access to only the resources they create. For example, you can use IAM policies to specify that each group can only launch EC2 instances with a specific tag that identifies them as the owner.
4. Set up AWS CloudTrail to monitor and log all API calls to AWS services, and set up CloudWatch alarms to alert you if any unusual activity is detected.

With these steps, you can ensure that each group can only access and modify the resources they create, and that they can't affect each other's resources. Additionally, by using CloudTrail and CloudWatch, you can monitor all activity in your AWS account and detect any unauthorized actions.